# VBA Range se adapte a celdas con información

Tags: excel, vba

tengo una duda con rangos en estas dos partes, el siguiente es un buscarv que toma como rango R2C3:R74C4 pero me gustaría saber si hay una forma para que se adapte a los datos de la tabla, porque hay tablas que llegan a la celda 100 y ese solo llega al 74, si hay alguna forma que se adapte a todos los datos de la tabla.

```
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(idx - 1).Name & "!R2C3:R74C4,2,0)"
```

Y el siguiente, es un un autofill, como el anterior, solo llega hasta el 74, para ver si hay alguna forma para que haga el autofill hasta la ultima casilla con información.

```
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D74")
    Range("D2:D74").Select
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 10.36
    Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Agradeciendo de antemano, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que has obtenido la última celda no vacía de una columna iterando. Puede funcionar pero no es lo más eficiente. te dejo aquí algunas generalizaciones que pueden resultarte útiles en el futuro.

He hecho una matriz falsa de datos para que los ejemplos se entiendan mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las celdas en rojo claro son celdas en blanco (las remarco porque es importante para algunas explicaciones).

**Obtener la última celda no vacía de una columna**

```
Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'Última celda no vacía en una columna específica
Debug.Print wk.Range("B" & wk.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print wk.Range("C" & wk.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código en la columna B dice que la última celda no vacía está en la fila 28 mientras que en la columna D es la fila 24. Si te fijas en la imagen de ejemplo, verás que es correcto.

Tu código iterando desde la primera fila solo funcionará siempre y cuando tus datos nunca puedan tener valores nulos/en blanco. Por ejemplo, si aplicamos tu código a `Campo1` diría que la última fila es es la 10, cuando sin embargo debajo hay datos. Es **crítico** conocer la estructura de tus datos o puedes cometer errores que no serían de programación sino de diseño de código incorrecto.

**Obtener la dirección de un conjunto de datos.**

En la imagen podemos ver que mi conjunto de datos entero va desde la celda B5 hasta la celda F28. Es decir, el rango es `B5:F28`. Con VBA podemos conocer este dato fácilmente si necesitamos aplicarlo en algún sitio (por ejemplo, dentro de tu fórmula BUSCARV). Es muy útil en escenarios donde el rango de datos va cambiando (por ejemplo, porque se añaden filas/columnas nuevas).

El único requisito es que *debes* conocer al menos una celda que esté dentro de esa matriz de datos. Por cuestiones de costumbre, se suele utilizar siempre la celda que está más arriba y más a la izquierda (B5 en nuestro ejemplo) aunque no es obligatorio (pero sí una buena costumbre para quien lea tu código).

```
'Obtener dirección del rango de datos usando la primera celda arriba a la izquierda
Debug.Print wk.Range("B5").CurrentRegion.Address(, , xlA1) 'en formato A1
Debug.Print wk.Range("B5").CurrentRegion.Address(, , xlR1C1) 'en formato R1C1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En una sola línea de código consigues las referencias del rango completo de datos. Además, puedes conseguirlo en formato A1 o en formato R1C1. Sobre la propiedad `Address` te recomiendo el siguiente enlace porque tiene varias opciones de configuración que pueden resultar útiles dependiendo de tus necesidades:

> [Propiedad Range.Address
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)

**Obtener última columna no vacía de una fila específica**:

```
'Última columna no vacía en una fila específica
Debug.Print wk.Cells(4, wk.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Debug.Print wk.Cells(5, wk.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código ha devuelto como columna no vacía en la fila 4 la 1 (de hecho, si miras la imagen, esa fila entera está vacía) pero devuelve la columna 6 (es decir, la letra F) para la fila 5 (donde están los encabezados).

Con estos ejemplos seguro que puedes adaptar tus futuros códigos de manera más eficiente. En tu caso, no puedo replicarlo porque no sé como es el original, pero algo así debería servir:

```
Sub test2()
Dim wkSource As Worksheet
Dim idx As Integer
Dim DataRange As String
Dim LastRow As Long


'dirección datos BUSCARV
idx = ActiveSheet.Index
Set wkSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(idx - 1)
DataRange = "'" & wkSource.Name & "'!" & wkSource.Range("B5").CurrentRegion.Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

'última fila no vacía de la columna A
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Observación"
Range("D2:D" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & DataRange & ",2,0)"
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Esei, estaba buscando una la forma de que contara todos los datos sin pararse en una celda vacía, tenia que rellenarla con algo. sos un crack

Answer (score 0):

Al final tuve que crear una variable que me identificara hasta donde se encontraba la ultima celda, en este caso "i", lo adapte a mis dos requerimientos y me funciona correctamente.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While Not Cells(i, 1) = ""
    i = i + 1
Wend
    '~~> This will let you work with Col B
    Set Rng1 = Columns(4)
idx = ActiveSheet.Index
HojaAnterior = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(idx - 1).Name
 
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Observación"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(idx - 1).Name & "!R2C3:R" & i & "C4,2,0)"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(i - 1, 4)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 10.36
    Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Es una solución válida. Pero la opción correcta es lo que comenta @Esei.  Iterar en cada fila para conocer la última fila con datos no es óptimo. Imagina tener una tabla con 1.000.000 de registros e iterar por ese millón de filas para saber donde está la última fila. O peor aún, varias tablas con cientos de miles de filas y tener que iterar por cada una de esas filas en todas las tablas. No es nada óptimo.
Saludos.